# Teclado numérico que permita numeros negativos en iOS con Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Tengo unos formularios en Flutter que tienen algunas entradas numéricas, aquí os muestro el código de uno de ellos donde con el atributo `TextInputType.numberWithOptions()`, estoy consiguiendo que dicho campo del formulario muestre un teclado numérico.:

```
TextField(
                                        textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                                        inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[TextInputFormatter.withFunction((oldValue, newValue) => newValue.copyWith(text: newValue.text.replaceAll(',', '.')))],
                                        controller: model.coreTemperatureController,
                                        keyboardType: const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                                        obscureText: false,
                                        autocorrect: false,
                                        enableSuggestions: true,
                                        decoration: const InputDecoration(floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.auto, labelText: "Core Temperature", hintText: "Core Temperature"),
                                      ),
```

El asunto es, que se deben permitir números negativos, de hecho el teclado que sale en Android lo perimte:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como véis aparece el signo "-", el cual, sin embargo, no aparece en iOS:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La pregunta por tanto es, como podría hacer para mostrar también ese signo "-" en iOS.

Answer (score 1):

El `TextInputType` tiene un parámetro `signed`, el cual por defecto está en `false`, así que podrías hacer algo como esto:

```dart
TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true, signed: true)
```